# Q: Creating a program in python to display a table of squares and cubes for a specified range of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to create a table of powers using python to display a table of squares and cubes for a specific range of numbers. Unfortunately, when I run the module the only thing shown in the shell is the users inputs for start and end number.

This is my code at the moment:

```
print("Table of Powers")
print()
start = int(input("Start number:\t"))
end = int(input("Stop number:\t"))
print()
def printTable(start, end):
    result = 1
    for x in range(start, end):
        print(x, x ** 2, x ** 3)
```

With this code I was hoping to create a table of powers from the users inputs, listing the numbers within the range, the squared numbers, and the cubed numbers.

Comment: It looks like you've only defined your function, you still need to call it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
Asking for "any advice" is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below:

```
print("Table of Powers")
print()
start = int(input("Start number:\t"))
end = int(input("Stop number:\t"))
print()

def printTable(start, end):
    result = 1
    for x in range(start, end):
        print(x, x ** 2, x ** 3)

# call your function like this:
printTable(start, end)
```